# I would like to know why this code is used to specify address

Tags: c, compiler-construction

```
#define NVRAM1_PAGE1_FIRST_ADDRESS   0x1000
extern volatile INT16U NVRAM_content[128]   __attribute((nodp, addr(NVRAM1_PAGE1_FIRST_ADDRESS)));
```

This array surely start address from `NVRAM1_PAGE1_FIRST_ADDRESS`
but How does this code work?
I mean, I was trying to find 'nodp' meaning but there was no information in code or manual.

Comment: What exact compiler is this code targeting?

Comment: Not sure what `__attribute((nodp` is supposed to mean. I'm assuming "no data packing", but if so, that's nonsense since the data is an array.

Comment: The code is non-standard C.  The only way of finding out what it does and how it does it is by looking at the documentation for the compiler you're using

Comment: This could be code from a project for MCS51 (8051 microcontroller family). The standard processor has a register called DPTR meaning "data pointer", and so this attribute **could** mean that the space can not be accessed by instructions using DPTR. @woehswe Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57524700/edit) your question and tell us about the target system and the compiler.